# LWUIT Table, constraint data

Tags: lwuit, tabular, nokia, s40

I am working in a table with multiple data inside. When I add only the header, I can see the data in a good way, and the columns with different sizes.

[image: Only headers]

But when I add the data, all the columns go crazy, the widths are adjust to the headers, and the data dissapear.

[image: With data]

How can I get to show every data in the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to derive table and override the method to create a cell then after a call to super set it to not end with 3 points.

You can also override the create constraint method and define percentages for the specific columns although this might not look good for all resolutions.

As a side note we made quite a few improvements to Table in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com) and integrated basic Asha support as well.